# how to input in a nested arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        a.add(1);

        a.add(2);

        l.add(a);

        a.clear();

        a.add(4);

        a.add(5);

        l.add(a);

        System.out.println(l+" | ");
    }
}
```

output - [[4, 5], [4, 5]] |

I want it to display - [[1,2],[4,5]]

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

You `clear` the list after adding it to the list of lists. You need to create a new list instead:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);
        l.add(a);
        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();  // new list!
        b.add(4);
        b.add(5);
        l.add(b);
        System.out.println(l+" | ");
    }
}
```

Background: When you create the list `a`, that is an object. You then add elements to that list. Then you add list `a` to `l`. `l` now has a reference to `a`, it does not make a copy of `a`. Then you clear `a`, which means `l` now has a reference to the empty list `a`. Then you add new items to `a`, and add `a` to `l` again. That means that `l` now has two references to the same list `a`. Hence when you print `l`, it prints `a` twice.

Comment: Could you not reuse `a`? Not the `ArrayList` `a` initially references, but after storing a reference to that `ArrayList` in `l`, can you not  assign a new `ArrayList` to `a`?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, good point, that would work too. I made a new variable in the hope to make it clearer for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

As @Robert has explained, `a` in the original code is a single reference added several times to the list `l`.  However, it is possible to simply create a copy of `a` list when adding it to the *outer* list using its constructor:

```java
List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
l.add(new ArrayList<>(a)); // copy added to l

a.clear();
a.add(4);
a.add(5);
l.add(new ArrayList<>(a)); // another copy added to l
System.out.println(l+" | ");
```

Another approach would be to avoid creating a temporary list `a` at all and populate list `l` using `Arrays.asList` which creates a fixed-size list:

```java
List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>(); // modifiable

l.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
l.add(Arrays.asList(4, 5));

System.out.println(l+" | ");
```

Answer (score -1):

you are  cleaning the list before printing, you can type the below code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        y.add(1);
        y.add(2);
        l.add(y);
        List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();  
        x.add(4);
        x.add(5);
        l.add(x);
        System.out.println(l+" | ");
    }
}
```